# Update Price based on dropdown list selection

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list populated by mysql working perfectly, I also have it displaying the price set by mysql, so far i'm happy.

What the issue is as it's a multiple dropdown list, it will only display what is chosen first, if I pick 2 or more selections, only the first price is shown.

My second issue is I want the prices to add up i.e. 1st Selection's price is £1.99, 2nd Selection's price is £2.99 so the total should be £4.98

Finally once i have all this working, I want to continue this onto the 2nd / 3rd / 4th dropdown boxes so that all the boxes add up giving me a combined total.

**Here's my html code to show you what i'm using:**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1">
  <? 
  include 'classes.php';
  $query="SELECT * FROM Sex_Table";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  ?>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team"  class="chzn-select" multiple tabindex="6" id="Sexdiv" name="Sexdiv" style="width: 300px;" onChange="getClothing(this.value),changePrice()">
  <option>Select Colour Type</option>
  <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
  <option value=<?=$row['ID']?> sex_price="<?=$row['Price']?>"><?=$row['Sex_Name']?>&nbsp;(£<?=$row['Price']?>)</option>
  <? } ?>
  </select><br /><br />
  <p id="Clothingdiv">
  <select style="width: 300px;" name="Clothing" disabled='disabled'>
  <option>Select Sex First</option>
  </select>
  </p><br />
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); </script>
  </form>
```

**and here's my js:**

```
function changePrice() {
 var sex_price = $("option:selected").attr("sex_price");
 $("#price_div").html("Price = £" + sex_price);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Ummm what is it that you're selling?

Comment: Not selling, just trying to make a calculator

Comment: Sandeep, nothing naughty, do not worry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of what you're trying to do, I've given each `select` element I want to calculate the `total` for a `class` so that they are not mixed up with other elements.

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calculate').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != 0) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#total').text('£' + total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="calculate" name="select-1">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1.99">£1.99</option>
    <option value="2.99">£2.99</option>
</select>

<select class="calculate" name="select-2">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1.99">£1.99</option>
    <option value="2.99">£2.99</option>
</select>

<select class="calculate" name="select-3">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1.99">£1.99</option>
    <option value="2.99">£2.99</option>
</select>

<span id="total">£0</span>
```

This will update the contents of `total` with the total price of each `select` element with class `calculate` when one of them is changed.

Comment: Hi, i copy and pasted your code into a new html to test it before incorporating it into my page but i could to get it to work, £0 stayed the same no matter what selection was chosen?

Comment: Hi deifwud, that's perfect, the thing is as my data comes from mysql and the dropdown lists are linked, when you select from the first list, it calls another page to display the contents here is the code (function getClothing(Sex_Table_ID) { $.ajax({ type: "get", url: "findClothing.php", data: { Sex_var: Sex_Table_ID }, error: function(error) { alert('System error, please try again.'); }, success: function(data){ //data is the response from the called file $("#select-2").html(data); //this changes the contents of the div to data that was returned}});}) is there anyway i can use the same page?

Comment: Quick question, how do you get it to divide the price instead of add to it?

Answer (score -1):

1. select with multiple should have the size attribute set as well, like this:

   `<select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team"  class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" id="Sexdiv" name="Sexdiv" style="width: 300px;" onChange="getClothing(this.value),changePrice()" size="10">`
2. Your jQuery script:

```js
$('select#Sexdiv').change(function() { 
    var value = 0;
    $("select#Sexdiv option:selected").each(function(){
        value += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#price_div").html("Price = £" + value);
});
```

Hmm?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i've pasted your code into my site, it's working but it's only adding up the first number i.e. 1.99 + 2.99 = £4.98, your code is adding it up to £3, also, if i only select 1 item, the price won't update until i select another item?